# Json line separator issue

Tags: php, json

Ok i'm stuck here 
i have a json output given from the code above

```
    $jsonurl = 'http://us.battle.net/api/d3/profile/'.$btag.'/';
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl,0,null,null);
$json_output = json_decode($json);
```

i can retrieve the data using, for example

```
$json_output->code
```

but, i have a specific data i need to retrieve

```
$json_output->timePlayed->demon-hunter
```

this one i cant retrieve because of the "-" in side the "demon-hunter" any tips?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, either use arrays:

```
$json_output = json_decode($json, true);
$json_output['timePlayed']['demon-hunter'];
```

Or use the following notation:

```
$json_output->timePlayed->{'demon-hunter'}
```

Comment: + for providing both samples.

Answer (score 0):

```
$type = 'demon-hunter';
$json_output->timePlayed->$type;
```